# Northwind Database

Tags: windows-xp, installation, sql-server, sql-management-studio

How can I Install Northwind Database in SQL Managment Studio 2008 R2?

Specification: Microsoft Windows **XP Service Pack3** 2002 version

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06616212-0356-46a0-8da2-eebc53a68034&displaylang=en

Download the MSI file from this location.  Double-click to install - actually, this extracts the files to (by default) C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases.

The script you want to run is "instnwnd.sql".

I've just run it on SQL Server 2008 & R2, and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download here: http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/30803